# Is it true that $\sigma$-field generated by finite subsets only has finite elements

Tags: measure-theory

I know there is a rule to generate a $\sigma$-field of finite subsets, as follows:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200943

However, I am not clear about how to show that there is not a element in $\sigma-field$ excluded by such collection of $\mathcal{K}$

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly your question is. You also do not really need quite so many links to the same link...

Comment: There is some ambiguity in your question. "Generated by finite subsets" suggests to me that you have some (possibly infinite) number of subsets each of which has a finite number of elements, but based on the link, you are thinking about a finite number of subsets each of which may have any (possibly infinite) number of elements.

Comment: Thank you, your comments. I mean given a set $\Omega$, there are finite subsets $A_i (i\in \mathcal{N})$ of $\Omega$. How to show the number of sets in the $\sigma$-field generated by $A_i (i\in \mathcal{N})$ is finite? In other words, how to prove that all sets in the $\sigma$-field can be represented as the shape of the union of any collection of elements of K (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200943)?